# Can I use Granger causality for missing data/ irregular time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, granger-causality, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have two time series and I want to look at their Granger causality. My data is from two irregular time series. Irregular here means sampling was done sporadically across 3 years. In some months, there is data every 3-5 days and some months there is no data.

What are the assumptions for Granger causality analysis? Can I use Granger causality with unevenly distributed/ missing time points?

Comment: There is an algorithm for granger causality and irregular or unevenly spaced time series: http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611972825.57

Comment: In a recent paper, we also propose a differet way to infer causal directions between irregular time series that does not rely on Granger : https://openreview.net/forum?id=4TSiOTkKe5P. Maybe that can help !